# Transparent Splashscreen Picture Qt

Tags: qt, png, splash-screen, alpha-transparency

I have created a splash-screen.png for my application. Unfortunately all the parts that should be transparent are drawn as a rectangle. To be able to understand better what I mean a small example-description: (I havnt got enough reputation to put a picture into the forum)

Lets say I have a png as splash-screen which shows a sphere. The sphere should stand for itself, but Qt draws a rectangle around it, which destroys all the atmosphere.

Would be very grateful if you know if there is another possibility to maintain the transparency around the object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-12820). As suggested in the bug report a workaround is to use a `QLabel` instead of a `QSplashScreen`.

Also check [this forum post](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3155). A solution is proposed by subclassing `QSplashScreen`.

Answer (score 2):

With the following flags, my png has a transparent frame:

splash.setWindowFlags( Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::SplashScreen | Qt::FramelessWindowHint );